# Number of times a particular element appears in a cell array

Tags: matlab

If I have an mxn cell array whose elements are either an integer or a vector of integers, how could I count how many times a particular integer occurs in the entire cell array? The integer could occur individually in a cell or in a vector in a cell.

My cells will look like this :

```
cell = { 1,2,3,4,5; [6,7,1], 2,7,8,9; 1,3,9,10, [1,2] }
```

Comment: Avoid using variable names like `cell` which are also built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, it is irrelevant where the elements are located in your cell, start flattening the data structure to a simple vector:

```
v=[mycell{:}];
```

To count the elements, using `histcounts` is a good choice

```
[x,c]=histcounts(v,min(v):max(v));
```

A more generic solution which does not rely on `v` containing integers is:

```
[x,c]=histcounts(v,unique(v));
```

In both cases x returns how often the corresponding value in v was found.

In case your MATLAB version does not know the `histcounts` function, replace it with `hist`

Answer (score 0):

A simple `cellfun()` will help you.
Such function will perform a given function (`ismember()` in our case) on every cell in a given cell array.
Let's say we want to look for `1`:

```
result=cellfun(@(x)ismember(1,x),cell);
```

and `result` will be a binary (boolean) matrix with 1 (`true`) in position (i,j) if `cell{i,j}` contains 1. To count how many items there are is enough to sum all the 1 in `result`:

```
numberOfItems=sum(result(:));
```

In our case then, `result` will have the form:

```
 1     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

and that is correct because 1 appears in `cell{1,1}`, `cell{3,1}` and also in the arrays that are in `cell{2,1}` and `cell{3,5}`. Now we can count the ones in `result`, or simply sum the entire matrix (its only values are 0s and 1s) to get `numberOfItems` as 4.

*Note*: naming a cell array `cell` is bad practice because `cell()`is a built-in Matlab function. If you name a variable or a function with built-in Matlab functions names, you won't be able to use such built-in function in your script.

**Update**: as @Daniel correctly pointed out, such solution might not be robust in case a vector contains the element we're looking for twice (or more). If there's a case in which, let's say, one of the arrays in `cell` is `[1 2 1]` we might want to take into account the fact that 1 appears twice in this array. So let's say we set `cell{2,5}=[1 2 1]`, by replacing `result` definition as

```
result=cellfun(@(x)sum(ismember(x,1)),cell)
```

now `result` has the form

```
 1     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     2
 1     0     0     0     1
```

and as you can see, now in `result(2,5)` there is 2, not 1. Using the very same trick as before (i.e. sum all entries in `result`) it's possible to count the number of occurrences of a given element.

Comment: `ismember` might be the wrong choice for cells like `{[1 2 1]}`